# How do I use Font Awesome Pro with NativeBase's Icon?

Tags: font-awesome, native-base

How do I use Font Awesome Pro with [NativeBase](https://nativebase.io)?

I can use a non-pro icon by following the documentation with, for example:

```
import { Icon } from 'native-base'
<Icon type="FontAwesome5" name="comment" />
```

but it’s unclear what else I need to do to ensure I can use a pro icon, [for example](https://fontawesome.com/icons/user-md-chat?style=solid):

```
<Icon type="FontAwesome5" name="user-md-chat" />
```

What do I need to do to get access to [pro icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=pro) through `native-base`’s [`Icon`](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#icon-def-headref) component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FontAwesome icon in native-base style by passing the `icon` property.
In your case, this should work:

```
import { Icon } from 'native-base';
import { faUserMd } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome";

<Icon as={FontAwesomeIcon} icon={faUserMd} />
```